# makefile syntax error while removing files

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

I am trying to make a make file function that cleans everything instead of 4 specific files:

```
all: clean compile run

compile: main.c util.c util.h
        @echo "-------------------------------------------"
        @echo "Compiling..."
        @gcc -o test main.c util.c

run:
        @echo "-------------------------------------------"
        @echo "Running the tests...."
        @echo "================================================================>
        @./test
        @echo "================================================================>
        @echo "Completed tests...."

clean:
        @echo "-------------------------------------------"
        @echo "Cleaning..."
        @rm -v !("main.c"||"makefile"||"util.c"||"util.h")
```

other functions do work but I get this error for $make clean:

```
-------------------------------------------
Cleaning...
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
make: *** [makefile:19: clean] Error 2
```

The line "rm -v !("main.c"||"makefile"||"util.c"||"util.h")" works normally when I type in on the console.What am I doing wrong?

ps: I am on ubuntu vm

I have tried to clean every file except 4 specific files with a makefile, but I got an error instead. The line works normally on the console.

Answer (score 0):

`make` runs each line of the Makefile in `/bin/sh`. If you want a different shell, you have to set the `SHELL` variable. In your case, start the Makefile with

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
```

But it's not enough, you also need to enable the `extglob` shell option. In GNU make, you can add the options directly to the variable:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash -O extglob
```

Answer (score 0):

As @choroba mentioned, you're using a special bash syntax, and make defaults to using `sh`.  You can use the following syntax which is compatible with `sh`:

```
clean:
   @ls | grep -xv "main.c\|makefile\|util.c\|util.h" | tr "\n" "\0" | xargs -0 rm
```

The `tr "\n" "\0"` converts the output to a null delimited list, and the `-0` tells xargs to treat each item on the list as a separate entity.   (This is to avoid issues where filenames might contain spaces).  Note that the `-x` on grep tells it to only match a whole line.